# shrink down CSS class/id names?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, minify

**tl;dr**, what's everybody's favorite CSS obfuscation tool?

---

I'm trying to figure out ways to optimize our CSS delivery to improve our uncompressed initial download.  We recently ran the compiled SASS through a minifier, which cut down the unnecessary whitespace, but I realized we've still got some bloat around the names we've given our classes.

I found a few questions on here asking about CSS obfuscation, but all of the answers have been focused around how that's a bad idea because obfuscation would make your CSS harder to read.  I really didn't think those were satisfactory answers, partly because that argument applies equally to Javascript (which people minify all the time), but mostly because [I've noticed some cool guys](http://google.com/?q=something) who make [pretty popular web applications](https://www.facebook.com/) doing exactly this (ostensibly, to the chagrin of everybody here on StackO).

I would've commented on these answers directly, but I haven't proven to the Overflowbots that I can talk, so I was forced to open a new question.

Anyhow, I know there's a way to do what I want, and I know some really big applications are already following this practice.  What are some good tools for minifying CSS class and id names for my site?  Something that can plug into the Rails pipeline would be great, but not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with the popular task-runner Gulp.js,  you can use the gulp-selectors plugin to automatically minimize your css selector names.

Read more about it here. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-selectors